# Capturando varíavel ajax usando php

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho o seguinte ajax :

```
$(".select").change(function()
{
  var select = $("#selectAparelho").val(); 
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: "POST", 
  url: "administrador.php",
  data: aparelho = select
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log(aparelho);
});
return false;
});
```

O problema é que quando o meu servidor php faz a verificação para ver se a variável está diferente de nula:

```
if (isset($_POST['aparelho']))
```

O servidor verifica que ela está nula porque naquele momento ainda não recebeu o valor, então ele retorna que ela está nula e depois não passa por aquele trecho de código para fazer a verificação novamente. O que eu preciso é uma forma de fazer o servidor passar novamente naquele local do código para verificar se a variável está vazia novamente, nesse momento ela já vai estar com o valor que recebeu do ajax e então vai realizar a operação que eu desejo.

Comment: Acho que o correto seria: data: {aparelho: select}

Comment: Você está retornando `aparelho` no `done`, mas deveria ser `data`. Tira o  `async`, senão não é ajax.

Comment: Marquei a pergunta como erro de digitação. Apesar de a minha resposta ter recebido dois upvotes, acho que seria justo ela ser transformada em comentário.

Comment: O async era só um teste desesperado heheh, agora estou printando minha data no log, e está trazendo tudo oque eu preciso, apenas com um problema, no log esta certo porém não é ataualizado na tela, como faço pra atualizar na tela as informações?

Comment: Você pode A) Localizar os elementos no DOM da página usando $("#minhaid") , $(".minhaclasse") ou mecanismos semelhantes e depois, B) utilizar uma mudança do valor do elemento ou do texto interno do elemento ou adicionar elementos dinamicamente. 
Respondi pergunta semelhante tem uns dias atrás:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170469/filtro-c-ajax-php/170723#170723

Mais a respeito:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/